# Magento 2: Cart price rule conditions not working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I have created a cart price rule with coupon code. The condition should be that the code should be applied for all categories except a few categories like this:
[image]

I don't know why but this is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: please run ``php bin/magento indexer:reindex``

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. It is happening because other categories are also assigned to the product.

Answer (score 0):

try to go to the action section in the rules and add the same conditions